Constructibility and a particular subset of $\omega_1$
Suppose that for each $x\subseteq\omega$, there is a least $\alpha_x$ so that $L_{\alpha_x}[x]\models ZFC+V=L[x]$; let $A=\{\alpha_x:x\subseteq\omega\}\subset\omega_1$. Is there anything interesting that we can say about $A$? Intuitively I feel like this may have something to do with existence of sharps, but right now I can't come up with any non-trivial statement.

Note that this is closely related to the admissibility spectrum problem but with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ replacing $\mathsf{KP}$. So everything below should be taken as folklore, IMO.

In fact, $A$ is just the set of countable "$\mathsf{ZFC}$-admissible" ordinal: in analogy with admissibility, say that an ordinal $\alpha$ is $\mathsf{ZFC}$-admissible iff $L_\alpha\models\mathsf{ZFC}$. This gives (under mild hypotheses) that $A$ contains a club, as well as the absoluteness fact (if $W$ is an inner model then $A^W=A\cap \omega_1^W$) from the previous version of this answer.
One direction is obvious: if $L_\alpha[r]\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ then $L^{L_\alpha[r]}=L_\alpha$ and so by Godel's analysis of $L$ we get $L_\alpha\models\mathsf{ZFC}$. In the other direction, we have that $A\subseteq\omega_1$ by a condensation argument (given $\alpha\in A$ via $r$, take the Mostowski collapse of a countable elementary submodel of $L_\alpha[r]$ containing $r$ as an element). So we just need to prove that every countable $\mathsf{ZFC}$-admissible ordinal is in $A$.  This splits into two cases, depending on whether $\alpha$ is a successor or limit $\mathsf{ZFC}$-admissible.

Successor case
Suppose $\beta<\alpha$ are each countable $\mathsf{ZFC}$-admissible ordinals and there is no $\mathsf{ZFC}$-admissible in the interval $(\beta,\alpha)$. Consider $\mathbb{P}=Col(\omega,\beta)^{L_\alpha}$. This is a set forcing in $L_\alpha$ and so, letting $G$ be $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $L_\alpha$ (which exists since $L_\alpha$ is countable), we get $L_\alpha[G]\models\mathsf{ZFC}$. But it's also easy to see that $L_\beta[G]\not\models\mathsf{ZFC}$, and so more generally no $\alpha'<\alpha$ has $L_{\alpha'}[G]\models\mathsf{ZFC}$. Since $G$ can be coded by a real $g$, we get that $\alpha\in A$ via $g$.

Limit case
This case itself splits into two subcases: either $\alpha$ is a limit of $\mathsf{ZFC}$-admissible ordinals, or there is some limit of $\mathsf{ZFC}$-admissibles $\beta<\alpha$ such that no $\mathsf{ZFC}$-admissible is in the interval $[\beta,\alpha)$ (in particular, $\beta$ itself is not $\mathsf{ZFC}$-admissible). The second subcase can be treated just as above: force with $Col(\omega,\beta)^{L_\alpha}$.
So this just leaves the case where $\alpha$ is literally a limit of $\mathsf{ZFC}$-admissibles. Of course by replacement inside $L_\alpha$ this means that the ordertype of the $\mathsf{ZFC}$-admissibles below $\alpha$ is itself $\alpha$, so let $(\beta_\eta)_{\eta<\alpha}$ list the $\mathsf{ZFC}$-admissibles below $\alpha$ in increasing order.
Obviously this case is messier. No set forcing will work here, since such a set forcing would live in some $L_{\beta_\eta}$ and so any real $s$ generated by such a forcing would have $L_{\beta_\eta}[s]\models\mathsf{ZFC}$. Instead, we need some class forcing trickery. This is doable by standard methods, but I don't have time to write it up at the moment; I'll try to fill this part of the argument in over the next few days, but you may want to ask this specific subcase as a separate question at MathOverflow (where you'll get an answer faster since there are more folks familiar with class forcing there than here).
EDIT: to be clear, the class forcing argument I have in mind makes use of almost disjoint forcing. The motivation is the proof of Theorem 1 in S.-D. Friedman's Introduction to the admissibility spectrum. The issue is step 1: Friedman starts by passing to a class-generic extension of the ground model (here $L_\alpha$) which is locally countable, i.e. satisfies "Every set is countable-or-finite." This is fine for admissibility, but not $\mathsf{ZFC}$-admissibility since of course $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that there are uncountable sets. So while the almost-disjoint coding part can (probably) be used here without significant change, a different trick is needed for the warm-up.

In $L$ we have that "for all real r $L[r]=L$" (since $r\in L$), so for every real $r\in L$ wouldn't we have $\alpha_r=\alpha_0$ and thus $A^L=A\cap\omega_1^L$ is just a singleton? Also, I was thinking if there's any assumptions that would allow us to deduce things such as "$A$ is/contains club in $\omega_1$" etc; is there a legitimate way to do this? Or perhaps this is just not true?

@RaczelChowinski Aha, not necessarily! $L[r]=L$ does not imply that $L_\theta[r]=L_\theta$ for all $\theta$. For example, if $r$ is a constructible real coding a copy of $L_{\alpha_0}$, then $\alpha_r>\alpha_0$ since $L_{\alpha_0}[r]\models$ "The universe is countable."

@RaczelChowinski As to whether $A$ contains a club in $\omega_1$: I suspect this is outright ZFC-provable. If I figure out the details in the next day or so I'll add it to this answer; alternatively, you could ask that as a separate question!

@RaczelChowinski Figured it out (mostly)! There's a final bit which is truly wonky, and you might want to kick that up to MO since I don't know when I'll be able to flesh it out; see my edit for details. (And of course my previous comment should say "ZFC+[model existence hypothesis]-outright provable," since ZFC alone doesn't even prove $A\not=\emptyset$.

Thanks for the edit! This answer here gives some very instructive guidelines for how to analyze the set $A$, so maybe I'll first try to work it out single-handedly :-D
